# The solution of $dx+zdy+ydz=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How to solve the following differential equation:

$$dx+zdy+ydz=0?$$

I know this question seems so easy, but I cannot remember its solution. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 6):

Hint 1: $$zdy+ydz=d(zy)$$
Hint 2: $$du+dv=d(u+v)$$
Hint 3: $$dF=0\implies F=\mathrm{const}$$

Comment: (or "locally constant" if in the appropriate setting)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}{{\rm e}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}$

${\rm d}\phi =0 $:
$$
{\partial\phi \over \partial x} = 1
\quad\imp\quad
\phi = x + {\rm f}_{0}\pars{y,z}
$$

$$
z=
{\partial\phi \over \partial y} = {\partial{\rm f}_{0}\pars{y,z} \over \partial y}
\quad\imp\quad
{\rm f}_{0}\pars{y,z} = zy + {\rm f}_{1}\pars{z}
$$

$$
\phi
=
x + zy + {\rm f}_{1}\left(z\right)
$$

$$
y=
{\partial\phi \over \partial z}
=
y + {\partial{\rm f}_{1}\pars{z} \over \partial z}
\quad\imp\quad
{\rm f}_{1}\pars{z} = \overbrace{C}^{\mbox{constant}}\,,
\quad
\phi = x + yz + C
$$

$$\color{#ff0000}{\large%
z \color{#000000}{\ =\ } {D - x \over y}
\quad\mbox{where}\quad
{\rm g}
\quad
\mbox{is an}\  {\color{#000000}{\it\mbox{arbitrary function}}}\ \mbox{of}\ x.}
$$
$D$ is a constant.